# how to install all dependencies packages globally?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, npm-install, create-react-app

When I create react app then there's create node_modules with more than thousands of packages under app/project folder and if I create more than ten apps then node_modules folder creates for each app with thousands of packages. so this way repeating same node_modules folder with thousands of packages which is not a good idea I think. After a long time system getting slow down with millions of files and folder created by npm based projects. if node_modules run from globally then app/project will install quickly and no one package will install duplicated/repeated.

I want to install a node_modules folder globally with thousands of packages instead locally(under app folder) when create/install any app/project.

I have tried all way using global command Like:

npm -g install

yarn-g install

Let me explain what exact i mean:
Suppose, If I create three react app

```
npx create-react-app my-app1

npx create-react-app my-app2

npx create-react-app my-app3
```

after setup all app, we get below like that node_modules with packages:

my-app1

```
-node-modules->p1,p2,p3....p999, so on..
```

my-app3

```
-node-modules->p1,p2,p3....p999, so on..
```

my-app3

```
-node-modules->p1,p2,p3....p999, so on..
```

See all same packages install multi times and repeating

Comment: This is not really problem. dependencies need to be installed locally to avoid version conflicts. Use global installs only for re-usable tools. Having thousands of folders does not lead to a performance loss. On slow computers, it may take time to open the folder using explorer, in that case just avoid opening that folder. At your level of understanding, there is nothing to be gained by opening that folder.

Comment: Also, npm caches your downloads, so that for each local project, it uses the cache to full fill dependency requirements, it does not re download every time you re-install a module for a different project.

Comment: As I know, the package install separately with version so i don't think version will conflict if this type of issue come with some packages then those can install under app but not all packages.

Comment: Package dependencies are quite complex which makes it not viable in real world projects to have this kind of sharing plus it's not just for your local copy. The project has to work on multiple environments such as production, staging, testing. Do you mean a workspace with related sub-projects? If so you can pull up node_modules to the root folder. If you mean sharing across unrelated projects that's not viable.

Comment: Please check question again i edited what i mean.

Comment: Oh okay, are these projects related? If so you can justify having them in a single workspace with the same `node_modules` folder. Unfortunately `create-react-app` does not allow for this. There's a discussion here about it.  https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1084 Your best options is to search for a different CLI tool that sets up react apps for you in this way. What most of the experienced developers do is setup a custom webpack config with multiple entrypoints in the same folder. But I'm not sure if you know to write webpack configs.

Comment: It's not happen with react app only. it happen with all node based app/projects.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is not the right way for project folder but if you want to try below line  try using (../)

> "start": "node ../node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start --reset-cache",

In your package.json file If you want to more detail please check this [link](https://github.com/nodejs/help/issues/681)

thanks

Answer (score -1):

```
npm install -g start-react-app
```

-g flag is used for globally

Comment: I am not talking about individual single package. That's install globally. I am talking about all dependencies packages under node_modules of the app/project

Comment: @npsingh I'll look back to that